# MDCChipField Swift - scrollable direction

Tags: ios, material-design, material-components, mdc-components, material-components-ios

I am trying to use MDCChipField, the material design component for Swift. 
I am implementing the 'input chip' type and am able to add the entered text as a chip with

```
let mdcSearchField = MDCSearchField()
mdcSearchField.addChip(chipView)
```

When the chips overflow in MDCChipField, they get added to next row. **How can i set the scrollable direction to horizontal** instead of vertical?

In the link,
https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#input-chips,
The placement section explains

> Input chips can be integrated with other components. They can appear:
>
> ```
>  - Inline with the text input cursor in a field
>  - In a stacked list
>  - In a horizontally scrollable list
> ```

How do i do a a horizontally scrollable list in code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My approach was this:

- Create a scrollable view
- create an offset of say 10 for padding between chips
- Add chips to the scrollable view
- Set the frame origin of the chip with the declared offset
- Add the chip's width to the offset plus the initial offset value (in this case 10)
- Increase the content width of the scrollable view, set the width to the total
  offset
- (add more chips/repeat)

On chip removal (if needed)

- Set initial offset back to 10
- Remove chip from parent scrollable view
- Loop through subviews and set the offset again to each of them
- Set the scrollable view new width using the total offset

Here is a sample in Swift
Configure initial layout

```
class ChipSample
{
    var tagXOffset = 10
    var tagPadding = 10
    func configureTagsView()
    {
        tagView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: view.bounds.width, height: 40))
        view.addSubview(tagView)
    }
```

Add a chip

```
    func addChip(name:String)
    {
        let chip = MDCChipView()
        chip.titleLabel.text = name
        chip.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        chip.sizeToFit()
        chip.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeChip), for: .touchUpInside)
        tagView.addSubview(chip)
        chip.frame.origin.x = tagXOffset
        chip.frame.origin.y = 0
        tagXOffset += tagPadding + chip.frame.width
        tagView.contentSize = CGSize(width: tagXOffset, height: tagViewHeight)
    }
```

Remove the chip

```
    @objc func removeChip(sender: MDCChipView!)
    {
        tagXOffset = tagPadding
        sender.removeFromSuperview()
        for subview in tagView.subviews {
            subview.frame.origin.x = tagXOffset
            tagXOffset += tagPadding + subview.frame.width
        }
    }
```

Comment: there are something in UIScrollview in the beginning, thus one have to check it so: if subview.isKind(of: MDCChipView.self) {...}